# Decreasing Sql Query Execution Time

Tags: sql-server

I am tackling with issue of time taken by SQL query to get executed. I have been through a thorough search, to decrease execution time. I am dealing with millions of records (obviously!).

My query is getting count of lectures from attendance table inner joined by 4 other tables. The problem is it takes 1-2 minutes to get executed. And this query is used in a loop whose count is dynamic(<10). And the connection timeout gets over. so it wont work.

My query is :

```
CREATE procedure [dbo].[Sp_TotalLecture_DateWise]
    (@CollegeId int = null,
     @AcademicYrId int = null,
     @Degreeid int = null,
     @StreamId int = null,
     @Semester nvarchar(50) = null,
     @SectionId int = null,
     @Course_Code nvarchar(100) = null,
     @frmdate nvarchar(50) = null,
     @ToDate nvarchar(50) = null)
as 
begin
    begin try
        Select 
            Count(at.StAttnd_Id) as TotalLecture 
        into 
            #t 
        from 
            ERP_AttendanceDetail as at 
        inner join 
            ERP_StudentAcadmicDetail as sad on at.Academic_Id = sad.Academic_Id 
        inner join 
            ERP_SectionAssign as Sa on sad.Section_ID = sa.Section_ID  
        inner join 
            ERP_StdntDetail as sd On sad.Stdnt_Id = sd.Stdnt_Id 
        inner join 
            ERP_Course as cd on sad.Course_Id = cd.Course_Id 
        Where 
            at.College_Id = @CollegeId 
            and SAD.AcademicYr_Id = @AcademicYrId
            and sa.Degree_Id = @Degreeid 
            and sa.Stream_Id = @StreamId 
            and sad.Semester = @Semester 
            and sad.Section_ID = @SectionId
            and cd.Course_Code = @Course_Code
            and at.Attnd_Date between convert(date, @frmdate, 106) 
                                  and convert(date, @ToDate, 106)    // If i remove search through date criteria, it will work fine and gives answer in 2-3 seconds.
        group by 
            sd.Stdnt_RegNo, sd.Stdnt_Name, sad.Stdnt_Id

    select max(TotalLecture) as TotalLecture 
    from #t

    drop table #t
end try
begin catch
end catch
end
```

Things I have already done are:

1. Used procedure, temp table ( as you can see)
2. Sets the primary key for all these tables mentioned with clustered index (as usual)
3. Created another index on the primary key field with non-clustered indexing

And the funniest part in this code is, if I remove the search through date criteria, it works perfect and gives answer in 2-3 seconds (but I cannot remove that).

And if there is no suitable solution to this. Kindly tell me how to maintain the connection for long, because it gets lost in between and no data is displayed. I kept command timeout for this specific procedure from .cs page is 2000000000.

Thanks.

Comment: At the end of the query, add `OPTION(OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN)`. For details, see [Query hints](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181714.aspx).

Comment: Performance questions should include `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` and some information about table size, index, current time performance, desire time, etc. `Slow` is a relative term and we need a real value to compare.

Comment: Thanks Mate(#TT).. You are awesome. Thank you...! Thanks to you to(#Juan) i will take care of that...

Comment: You should also consider dropping the sp_ prefix, or even better removing all prefixes. The sp_ prefix is a no go for a number of reasons and can cause some levels of performance challenges. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix

Answer (score 0):

Try below Query, hopefully this will work

```
Select sd.Stdnt_RegNo, sd.Stdnt_Name, sad.Stdnt_Id, at.StAttnd_Id Into #t 
from ERP_AttendanceDetail as at 
inner join ERP_StudentAcadmicDetail as sad  on  at.Acadmic_Id=sad.Acadmic_Id 
inner join ERP_SectionAssign as Sa on sad.Section_ID=sa.Section_ID 
inner join ERP_StdntDetail as sd On sad.Stdnt_Id=sd.Stdnt_Id 
inner join ERP_Course as cd on sad.Course_Id=cd.Course_Id 
Where at.College_Id=@CollegeId 
and SAD.AcadmicYr_Id=@AcademicYrId
and sa.Degree_Id=@Degreeid 
and  sa.Stream_Id=@StreamId 
and  sad.Semester=@Semester 
and sad.Section_ID=@SectionId
and cd.Course_Code=@Course_Code
and at.Attnd_Date between convert(date,@frmdate,106) and convert(date,@ToDate,106)


Select Count(StAttnd_Id) StAttnd_Id into #t1 from #t
Group by Stdnt_RegNo, Stdnt_Name, Stdnt_Id


Select MAX(StAttnd_Id) StAttnd_Id from #t1
```

Comment: Thank You Sir. But it still took 1 min and 1 sec. to get executed.

Answer (score 0):

Performance is depend on the all table structures and data volume. Without looking at perfect solution is little foggy.

try another method, 
fill 2 or 3 required fields of each table in #temp1, #temp2....#temp5 tables. Create index on them which are using in join
create index on date field as well and make sure convert date Convert(date,@frmdate,106) at the time of filling in #temp 
and then write the join queries.

do not use convert(date,@frmdate,106) at the time of filter as you have already converted date in to #temp

Filter will be like....

```
 and (at.Attnd >=@frmdate and at.Attnd<=@ToDate)
```

and after that store the join query result in #t

```
Select Count(StAttnd_Id) StAttnd_Id into #t1 from #t
Group by Stdnt_RegNo, Stdnt_Name, Stdnt_Id


Select MAX(StAttnd_Id) StAttnd_Id from #t1
```

One more thing.... try to fill #temp1, #temp2..... #Temp5 before starting the loop, if possible